# Swift 4 : substring(with:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript

Tags: swift, swift4

I am using a decode function for html. But I am getting this warning. How can I get rid off?

```
func decode(_ entity : String) -> Character? {

    if entity.hasPrefix("&#x") || entity.hasPrefix("&#X"){
        return decodeNumeric(entity.substring(with: entity.index(entity.startIndex, offsetBy: 3) ..< entity.index(entity.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)), base: 16)
    } else if entity.hasPrefix("&#") {
        return decodeNumeric(entity.substring(with: entity.index(entity.startIndex, offsetBy: 2) ..< entity.index(entity.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)), base: 10)
    } else {
        return characterEntities[entity]
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you Googled `substring(with:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript`? There seems to be a lot there

Comment: Yeah I searched off course. But I didnt find works answer for me. And I didn't understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `someString.substring(with: someRange)` just needs to be `someString[someRange]`.

So change:

```
entity.substring(with: entity.index(entity.startIndex, offsetBy: 3) ..< entity.index(entity.endIndex, offsetBy: -1))
```

with

```
entity[entity.index(entity.startIndex, offsetBy: 3) ..< entity.index(entity.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)]
```

In other words, change the `.substring(with:` to `[` and change the closing `)` to `]`.

The result is a `Substring`, not `String`. So you may need to wrap the result in `String( )` to get a `String` from the substring result.